# User input string handling

Tags: c, newline, fgets

I have a simple C function where, I have a user supply a path name and the function checks it to see if it is valid file or not.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char  cFileChoice[256];
    FILE * rInputFile;
    unsigned int cFileLength;

    printf("\nPlease supply a valid file path to read...\n");

    fgets(cFileChoice, 255, stdin);
    cFileLength = strlen(cFileChoice) - 1;

    if (cFileChoice[cFileLength] == "\n") {
        cFileChoice[cFileLength] = "\0";
    }
    rInputFile = fopen(cFileChoice, "r");
    if (rInputFile != NULL) {
        printf("Enter 'c' to count consonants or enter 'v' for vowels: ");
    }
    else {
        printf("Not a valid file\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Only after running this the file returns as invalid no matter if it is a valid path or not.  I have removed the `newline` character `\n` and replaced it with a `null terminator` `\0` but, it still doesn't recognize a correct path.

I have very minimal experience with C and I'm not sure where I should be looking to correct this?

EDIT:

These are the compile warnings I received:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:15:34: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
     if (cFileChoice[cFileLength] == "\n") {
                                  ^
test.c:16:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         cFileChoice[cFileLength] = "\0";
                              ^
```

Again I'm not sure how to correct these "warnings"?

Comment: Compile with warnings enabled. You will have quite a few of them. Come back after you fixed them.

Comment: @H2CO3 I posted the compile warnings but, I'm not sure how to correct them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"\n"` and `"\0"` are string literals (and `"\0"` is a particularly weird string literal, at that).  You want to compare to character literals: `'\n'` and `'\0'`.

You also have a single `=` where you want a `==` in the second comparison (the one that should be comparing to `'\0'`).

You should read the [`comp.lang.c` FAQ section 8, *Characters and Strings*](http://c-faq.com/charstring/index.html).

Comment: I appreciate the link I will read up on it.  Awesome! I fixed the quotes and its working.  I have a lot to learn and will read through the link you put up, Thanks again.